# Ignore "An item with the same key has already been added."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, oracle11g

Suppose I have this table structures:

[image]

To query the **REQUEST** for both table, I created a view with a *UNION*.

As a result, both the ID's for `INVOICE_REQUEST_ID` and `DELIVERY_REQUEST_ID` are queried as `REQUEST_ID`. To identify the type, I created a *dummy flag* `REQUEST_TYPE`. When I try to bind the data to a `GridView`, as I predicted, an error occur:**An item with the same key has already been added.**

**UPDATE**

I use custom GridView with this with CheckBox on my *GridViewControl.ascx*:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPc" runat="server" CssClass="div-grid" ScrollBars="Auto">  
<asp:GridView ID="gvListing" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
            OnRowDataBound="gvListing_RowDataBound" skinid="gvListing"
            onselectedindexchanged="gvListing_SelectedIndexChanged"
            onpageindexchanging="gvListing_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="50" >

<FooterStyle CssClass="grid-footer" />

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckAll">
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged" CssClass="select-all"/>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" CssClass="listing-checkbox"/>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

And bind data with this C# code:

```
//assuming that ucLAD is the CustomGridView
ucLAD.DataKeyName = def.ID_REQUEST; // here I assign the DataKeyName
ucLAD.BindGrid(dt); //dt is a datatable that contains my view
```

My resolution is to:

1. Ignore the error in try-catch. (How can I do this?)
2. To create a composite key for the `REQUEST_ID` and `REQUEST_TYPE`.
3. Create a dummy key for both request type.

Comment: Sharing the code you used for the grid would help tell you exactly what to fix

Comment: Ok sir, let me update my question.

Comment: `DataKeyName` is a property of the grid, not of the user control. you could expose the grid as public and use something like, `ucLAD.gvListing.DataKeyName = "YOUR_KEY";` Setting it on the user control won't work. P.S: Just cause I answer questions, doesn't make me sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set your key to have multiple columns, you only have to set the [`DataKeyNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="REQUEST_ID,REQUEST_TYPE"
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
```

Comment: Sir but in my case I have GridViewControl.ascx

Comment: Even if your grid is in a user control, you still have a `GridView` inside that user control, and you can set this there. You can expose the property of the grid by creating a corresponding property for the user control.